# My regex expression is not working properly in classic ASP

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I have a ASP page that I was asked to change European first name and last name such as

André-Anne Côté
Vincent Régis
After much digging around I came up with this expression

```
ValidationExpression="^([\u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z'\-]{1,50})$"
```

The expression seems to work but I cannot get it to limit the text size to 50 chars.  I tried various iterations of this such as

```
ValidationExpression="^[\u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z'\-]{1,50}$"
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?  Can anyone help ?

Comment: Related reading: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Adding spaces to you character group, your expression works for me... i.e. `^[\u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z'\-\s]{1,50}$`

Comment: @Biffen I saw that blog post a few times when I was googling around.  I see that point of it and I don't see that point of it.

Comment: @ClasG Frankly I am not sure why spaces helped, but they did.  So, thanks.

Comment: @Waddaulookingat I guess it's because your expression only matches characters (non space) between the start of line `^` and end of line `$`. As long as your name doesn't contain spaces, validation should succeed with your old expression, otherwise fail...